# Python 3 throws name 'InputLayer' is not defined when trying to add tensorflow input layer

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I've been trying to implement a simple network which takes images of varying sizes and colorizes them. I've been trying to use an input layer with this model, but it seems that python has "changed its mind" since I last worked on this project, and no longer recognises InputLayer

I've checked my imports for malformed library names, and no errors have been thrown. What has changed since I ran this code last and what should I change about what I have now? For context, I'm using the newest version of tensorflow and all other libraries on python 3. I don't remember how I last ran this script, but it appears to have been on a legacy version of at least one of the libraries I'm using.

My imports:

```
from skimage import color
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization,UpSampling2D,Conv2DTranspose,Add,AvgPool2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
import sys
!pip install opencv-python
import cv2
from os.path import isfile, join
```

The area causing errors:

```
colormodel = Sequential()
colormodel.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(None, None, 1)))
```

If anything else is needed of me, please comment what I've left out

I've revieved this error message when trying to load in the code block on jupyter notebook:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-21-13604e43d8ef> in <module>()
      1 colormodel = Sequential()
----> 2 colormodel.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(None, None, 1)))
      3 colormodel.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
      4 colormodel.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
      5 colormodel.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))

NameError: name 'InputLayer' is not defined
```

Comment: Please don't mix keras and tf.keras in your imports, it will bring you random errors, choose one and stick to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in your `import`:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import InputLayer
```